# React how to access props from constructor and then make a component based on the props/state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not really sure how to properly ask this question but I will explain what I'm trying to do here:

So I have this parent Component which creates a Component like so:

```
<CurrentTemperature cityName={this.state.cityName}></CurrentTemperature>
```

The CurrentTemperature Component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "../App.css";

export default class CurrentTemperature extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            temperature: 0,
            cityName: this.props.cityName,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //fetch the temperature from api here
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="city-temperature">
                    {this.state.cityName} {this.state.temperature}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

All I'm trying to do is read the city name from the parent, then fetch the current temperature from my API, and then display both of those in the Component. But if I try to console.log(this.props.cityName) from anywhere other than from inside the city-temperature div, I always get an empty string. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cityName is the state of the parent component. I guess the parent component would get the "cityName" asynchronously. right? If this is the case, You have to put the temperature in the parent component as its state. And you have to insert the API call in the parent component. CurrentTemperature component will behave like a pure function component.

```js
const CurrentTemperature = ({temperature, cityName}) => {
    return (
        <div className="city-temperature">
            {cityName} {temperature}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I guess this is not only the solution but also the best DX.

Comment: Yup, this is what I ended up doing, thanks. Also, I haven't seen this way of declaring a Component yet, temperature and cityName act as props, right?

Comment: yes, it's a component with props temperature and cityName.

Comment: Just to elaborate on your question, this syntax is destructuring the props objects as function parameters. There is a good article explaining this here - https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6

This is good if you only want to destructure a few props, otherwise I find it easier to read using the conventional method of destructuring inside the function `const { prop1, prop2 } = props`.

YMMV

Answer (score -2):

You can remove `this` in your constructor, and then use `this.state.cityName`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    temperature: 0,
    cityName: props.cityName,
  };
}
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Props and this.props in the constructor are both the same thing.

Comment: That is the correct syntax. And cityName isn't needed to be in state.

Comment: That's what I though, maybe using `getDerivedStateFromProps` is the better approach here.